# Rust: Sending a parking_lot::RwLockReadGuard

Tags: multithreading, rust, synchronization, thread-safety, rwlock

Here is the simplified code I am trying to write:

```rust
use parking_lot::RwLock;

let buffers: Box<[RwLock<MyBuffer>]> = Box::new([ ... ]);
let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

thread::spawn(move || {
    let guard = buffers[ ... ].write().unwrap();
    expensive_computation(&mut *guard);
    sender.send(guard.downgrade()).unwrap();
});

for message in receiver.iter() {
    // Handle the message
}
```

However, [`RwLockReadGuard` is not `Send`](https://github.com/Amanieu/parking_lot/issues/139), so this code does not compile.

How should I solve the problem of sending a `RwLockReadGuard` across the thread boundary?

Comment: From a quick look, I'd guess you should wrap the `RwLock` in an `Arc`, and send a reference to the lock rather then the lock guard. (I.e. use `Arc<RwLock<MyBuffer>>` as the item type in your slice.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's a good idea, but the problem is that now writers can race for the lock while it's sitting in the mpsc queue.

Comment: The race should be prevented by `RwLock`. Or why do you think that `Box<...>` is better thant `Arc<...>`. @Sven Marnach: I suppose you mean `Arc<[RwLock<MyBuffer>]>`?

Comment: @CoronA No, I meant what I said. The thread tries to return a reference to a specific item in the slice, so we need an `Arc` for each item.

Comment: @Coder-256 You'll probably have to come up with a separate mechanism to prevent that, like moving the items that have already been processed out of the slice. I don't have enough context to make a good suggestion here.

Comment: First, thank you both for helping. I am trying to implement triple buffering. The goal is to have one thread that repeatedly writes data into one of three buffers, then passes a read lock back to the main thread, and alternates writing to the two remaining buffers so that the main thread can easily access the most recently updated buffer. I created a workaround by sending the `RwLock` for the most recent buffer then leaving it up to the main thread to actually lock it; however, I want to avoid unlocking/relocking and manually updating.

Comment: Also I should mention that in my particular case I am using `Box::leak` to get a `&'static [RwLock]` reference since I use the buffers during the whole program and it's more efficient this way, but otherwise you would be right, I would need an `Arc` in order to access the `RwLock` from 2 threads at a time. I write a reference to the freshest `RwLock` into a mutex (but I will probably switch to an atomic pointer for performance since I'm using the static lifetime anyway).